# How to ensure that two properties are always overriden together in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have an abstract parent class as follows:

```py
import abc

class Parent(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def prop1(self):
       return None
    
    @property
    def prop2(self):
       return None
```

Is there a way to enforce the constraint that when either of `prop1` or `prop2` is overriden in an inheriting class, the other is also overriden?

Comment: What's the point? Even if they override it, they could just call the parent version.

Comment: This suggests that they shouldn't be two separate properties. Make it one property that holds a tuple.

Comment: Unfortunately, it wouldn't make sense to combine them into a single property for me. I am looking for solutions more strict that just documenting that both need to be overrriden together or neither should be overriden.

Comment: You may be able to do introspection in the `__init__()` method to determine if the properties come from the same class. I'm not sure of the specific details.

Comment: What *are* they that it doesn't make sense to define them as one property, but it does make sense to require both to be overriden together? What *semantics* need to be preserved by the two overrides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can enforce the constraint that when either `prop1` or `prop2` is overridden in an inheriting class, the other is also overridden by using a metaclass:

```
import abc

class EnforceOverrideMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if "prop1" in attrs and "prop2" not in attrs:
            raise TypeError("When overriding `prop1`, `prop2` must also be overridden")
        if "prop2" in attrs and "prop1" not in attrs:
            raise TypeError("When overriding `prop2`, `prop1` must also be overridden")
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)

class Parent(metaclass=EnforceOverrideMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def prop1(self):
       return None
    
    @property
    def prop2(self):
       return None
```

```
class Child(Parent):
    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return "Value for prop1"

    @property
    def prop2(self):
        return "Value for prop2"
```

the Child class correctly overrides both prop1 and prop2 from the Parent class. When creating an instance of Child, the constraint of overriding both properties will be satisfied.

```
child = Child()
print(child.prop1)  # Output: Value for prop1 in Child
print(child.prop2)  # Output: Value for prop2 in Child
```

[Python Documentation on Metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses)

Comment: Interesting solution! But, in your last code block as you have `Child` defined, it should work, right? Because both `prop1` and `prop2` are overridden? Did you mean to refine `Child`?

Comment: This is a case where the check could be made in `Parent.__init_subclass__` without introducing a custom metaclass and the composability issues they can impose.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use a combined property (`_thetwothings` below) with two proxy properties prop1 and prop2, and tell in comments of `prop1` and `prop2` that those should never be changed in a subclass. This should be enough said. In this way, nobody will accidentally change just `prop1` or `prop2` separately.

> We're all consenting adults here -- Guido van Rossum

```py
import abc


class Parent(abc.ABC):
    @property
    def _thetwothings(self):
        return None, None

    @property
    def prop1(self):
        """The usual docstring"""
        # Never change this in a subclass!
        # Edit _thetwothings, instead 
        return self._thetwothings[0]

    @property
    def prop2(self):
        """The usual docstring"""
        # Never change this in a subclass!
        # Edit _thetwothings, instead 
        return self._thetwothings[1]


class ChildDefault(Parent):
    ...


class ChildVariant(Parent):
    _thetwothings = ("first", "second")


class ChildPropVariant(Parent):
    @property
    def _thetwothings(self):
        return "foo", "bar"
```

which would work like this:

```py
>>> child_default = ChildDefault()
>>> child_default.prop1 is None
True
>>> child_default.prop2 is None
True

>>> child_variant = ChildVariant()
>>> child_variant.prop1
'first'
>>> child_variant.prop2
'second'

>>> child_propvariant = ChildPropVariant()
>>> child_propvariant.prop1
'foo'
>>> child_propvariant.prop2
'bar'
```